# Javascript - adding new value in object from another function?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have this piece of code:

```
_.each(events, function (e) {
    filter_value = e[self.color_field][0];                                                                                    
        if (!self.all_filters[e[self.color_field][0]]) {
            filter_item = {
                value: filter_value,
                label: e[self.color_field][1],
                color: self.get_color(filter_value),
                avatar_model: (_.str.toBoolElse(self.avatar_filter, true) ? self.avatar_filter : false ),
                is_checked: true,
                test: 'test'
            };                                       
            self.all_filters[e[self.color_field][0]] = filter_item;
        }
        if (! _.contains(self.now_filter_ids, filter_value)) {
            self.now_filter_ids.push(filter_value);
        }  
});
```

I want it to extend `filter_item` object with new key/pair value (specifically change `test` value with more meaningful one).

The value I want to add for `test` key I defined like this:

```
new instance.web.Model('hr.employee').query(["week_busyness"]).filter([["id", "=",e[self.color_field][0]]]).first().then(function(result){
    return result.week_busyness //this is the value I need to add for test 'key' inside filter_item
});
```

So I tried wrapping this function around filter_item, but then it just stops working at all (what I mean wrapping - starting function just before `filter_item` is defined, then ending after filter item and assigning value inside it).

I also tried updating `filter_item` after it was initially defined. Inside my function I added like this: `filter_item.test = result.week_busyness`. That was applied, but it was not applied where actually above function is used. So such approach didn't do anything.

If I assign my function to variable like this:

```
week_busyness = new instance.web.Model('hr.employee').query(["week_busyness"]).filter([["id", "=",e[self.color_field][0]]]).first().then(function(result){
        return result.week_busyness
    });
```

and assign to `test` key, then it assigns function object not the actual returned value.

So the question. How could I properly insert that value inside `filter_item` object?..

**Update**
"week_busyness" (if we could call it) function returns hours in float type for employee whose id was provided - `e[self.color_field][0]]]` returns id of employee (and it is used in a filter to find right employee). Also `result` is an employee object.

Comment: That's underscore.js, not jQuery.

Comment: You cannot turn this asynchronous code into synchronous. There is not sufficient context in your question to determine how to make your changes to `all_filters` asynchronous.

Comment: @DarkFalcon so u mean there is no way to just simply add the value I want there?..

Comment: It's not really possible to debug this code without understanding the return values. What is supposed to be returned by `new instance.web.Model('hr.employee').query(["week_busyness"])` ? You should put a `debugger;` statement in your code and then run the code with Chrome Dev Tools open in order to step through the code and see what's happenning. I'd suggest putting one inside of and after the `new instance.web.Model('hr.employee').query(["week_busyness"])` that's failing. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: @Andrius: No. That callback likely is not called until long after the rest of that function has finished executing.

Comment: @DarkFalcon yeah, thats what I was seeing. But can't figure our how to 'extend' that original method so it would have additional key/value inside filter_item object..